# Using GSON to parse an array of objects that contains an object that contains a needed String

Tags: java, json, gson

To start, here is the item I am trying to parse. Right now, I am trying to obtain the value of the "name" key from this JSON. I haven't had trouble using GSON to obtain other necessary variables, but this one is much trickier than those.

```
 "types": [
        {
            "slot": 2,
            "type": {
                "url": "https://www.pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/",
                "name": "poison"
            }
        },
        {
            "slot": 1,
            "type": {
                "url": "https://www.pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/",
                "name": "grass"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Here is my code that allowed me to successfully create the treecko object from all of the desired variables besides the array of Types.

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            PokedexMemberJava treecko = gson.fromJson(jsonPokemon, PokedexMemberJava.class);
```

The classes I used to attempt to create the object from the JSON. When I attempted to create the object from the JSON, all variables were successfully loaded besides the array of Types, which was created as null. These other variables were loaded from a different section of JSON, but I included a link to this at the bottom of this post if looking at it is necessary.

```
public class PokedexMemberJava {
    int id;
    String name;
    int height;
    int weight;
    Types[] type;

public PokedexMemberJava(int id, String name, int height, int weight){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
}


}

public class Types {
    public Type typeObject;
    public int slot;

public Types (Type typeObject, int slot){
    this.typeObject = typeObject;
    this.slot = slot;  
}

}

public class Type {
    public String url;
    public String name;

public Type (String url, String name){
    this.url = url;
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out and trying to get the name variable with other libraries like org.json to no avail. I only included the JSON of the part I was trying to obtain above. If for some reason you want to see what the entire JSON object would look like that I'm trying to parse, you can find it here: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/252/ . Also, I apologize for any mistakes or poor formatting of this post. It is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have json field name mismatch:

1. Instead of `Types[] types;`, you have `Types[] type;` which does not match`types` property in json
2. Instead of `Type type;`, you have `Type typeObject;` which does not match `type` property in json

So you have 2 options:

1. Rename java field to match the json property OR
2. Use `@SerializedName` to override the property name:

   ```
   public class PokedexMemberJava {
       @SerializedName("types")
       Types[] type;
       ...

   public class Types {
       @SerializedName("type")
       public Type typeObject;
   ```

Comment: I did not realize that the actual variable name within each class had to match what its corresponding property is in JSON. Thanks for the help!